# Java: Create program that prints integer n number of times - how to get n to work

Tags: java, for-loop, integer

I am currently working on a program that should produce the desired output:

```
1
2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5
etc
```

Basically, it will be a class function that takes an int n and, starting from 1, prints the number n many times.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
public class NumberTaker {

    public static void calculateNum(int a ){

        int b = 0;

        int c = b;

        int numTimes = a;

        for (int i = 1; i < numTimes; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < numTimes; j++) {
                if (i == j) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Of course this will only print each number once, I'm at a loss for how to print each number n times. Can anyone give me any suggestions?

Comment: Try removing `if (i == j) {`

Comment: This is obviously for a class, so I don't want to just give you the answer.  One way to approach this would be to simplify it so that it does part of what you need, correct, then add more parts to it.  For example, try to start with just a list of numbers.  (I'm starting you off like this because you've made the code too complicated.  Simplifying it will help you see the error.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numTimes; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
     }
     System.out.println();

}
```

The outer loop loops from `1..numTimes`. The inner loop loops from `1...i` times and hence you can print the value of `i` `i` times.

Comment: And it's kind of uncool to just give people answers to their course work.  This is not how people learn.

Comment: @markspace The OP has already done the most part of it. The loop condition was only missed. So, it is not like I'm doing OP's full homework

Answer (score 0):

This is not causing the error in your program but just a note: you are declaring and initializing the variables b and c yet you are not using them anywhere in your loop so they are just wasting unnecessary space. In fact, you don't even need the variable numTimes. Just use your parameter a.

That being said, the mistake you were making is in if the clause. You want to print each i value j times but your code is only printing out to the console when i equals j. Hence, this is why it is only printing each value one time (1 2 3 4) rather than what you wanted.

Try the follow code and let me know if you have any questions. Good luck!

```
public static void calculateNum(int a ){
        for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                    System.out.print(i + " ");

            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
```